# Alignment issues and text spacing

Tags: html, css

I'm experiencing an issue with my DIV (trying to replicate a business card). http://jsfiddle.net/FvpPk/1/

I can't get rid of the extra space between lines. I tried margin-bottom: 1px in H1 and P but without success. What should I do? (note that it was OK before implementing normalize.css but I've not been able to locate what in normalize.css caused this)

Thanks for your help

```
<div id="addressbox">
    <h1>ifdhod doifhdosfh odhfdsofhdo</h1>
    <p> 546, avenue ffds dfdsfd</p>
    <p> A-1234 fdfdfsf (Austria)</p>
    <div id="addressbox-bottom">
    <ul id="contact">
<li><i class="icon-phone-sign"></i> +352 691 123.456</li>
<li><i class="icon-envelope"></i><a href="#"> geyi@iyiyiy.com</a></li>
<li><i class="icon-map-marker"></i><a href="#"> itinéraire</a></li>

</ul>
    </div>



#addressbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 20px;
    padding: 0 10px 10px 15px;
    width: 355px;
    height: 120px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #ccc;
}
#addressbox-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 3px 10px 10px 15px;
    width: 355px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #2970A2;
}
#addressbox h1 {
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 13px;
}
#addressbox p {
    color: #667878;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 13px;
}

#contact li {
    display: inline;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    list-style: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 13px;
}
#contact li a {
    border-bottom: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you wanted.

http://jsfiddle.net/FvpPk/2/

```
#addressbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 20px;
    padding: 0 10px 10px 15px;
    width: 355px;
    height: 120px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #ccc;
}
#addressbox-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 3px 10px 10px 15px;
    width: 355px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #2970A2;
}
#addressbox h1 {
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 13px;
}
#addressbox p {
    color: #667878;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 0.50;
}

#contact{
    margin-top: 5px;
}

#contact li {
    display: inline;
    /*padding-top: 5px;*/
    padding-right: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    list-style: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 13px;
}
#contact li a {
    border-bottom: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```